# PHP version: module version is higher than installed PHP version

Tags: php, eclipse

I am using eclipse oxygen for php developers, trying to run php project with version 5.6.

Installed php version: 5.6

PHP version in project facets: 5.6

I tried to follow the the below tutorial, however I could not find php -> interpreter in neither project level nor workspace level.

[https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwinstprf.html](http://eclipse%20forum)

How to resolve module(project?) version complaint?

Answer (score 2):

I run in the same problem when I tried to run/debug a PHP project via `Run As -> Run On Server`.

Since you have not developed in detail your case I will try to present my case such that you might understand what might cause the problem and how to fix it.

So what I did was to choose the `Run -> Run As -> Run on Server` menu when a wizard-like dialog box was shown. I choose the PHP's Built-in Server, specified a PHP installed executable (like 5.6) then in the next screen ("Modify the resources that are configured on the server") by trying to move my project from the "Available" list to the "Configured" list I've got a notice error like the one you mentioned in the title. In my case the project was configured with PHP 7.1 while the PHP executable chosen in the "Run on Server" dialog box was 5.6, thus the conflict.

So the problem is that your project is defined to be validated by one PHP version while you are trying to run/debug it with another PHP version. What you can do to fix this is one of the following:

- either choose a PHP executable for your "Run on Server" session that is compatible with the project's PHP version; this can be done easy right in the "Run on Server" screen .
- either configure your PHP project to be validate by the same PHP version as the one you are trying to run/debug your project with; this can be done by right-click the project -> Properties -> PHP -> Validation then choosing the right PHP version

I hope it helps.

Comment: this second option you mentioned simple doesn't exist

Comment: Well, it does in my "Eclipse for PHP Developers", Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2): https://imgur.com/a/sObeYCm